# What should be taken as m in m estimate of probability in Naive Bayes

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition, naivebayes

What should be taken as m in m estimate of probability in Naive Bayes?
[image]
So for this example [image]

what **m** value should I take? **Can I take it to be 1**.
 Here p=prior probabilities=0.5.

So can I take P(a_i|selected)=(n_c+ 0.5)/ (3+1)

For Naive Bayes text classification the given P(W|V)=[image]

In the book it says that this is adopted from the m-estimate by letting **uniform priors and with m equal to the size of the vocabulary.**
But if we have only 2 classes then p=0.5. So how can `mp` be **1**? Shouldn't it be `|vocabulary|*0.5`? How is this equation obtained from m-estimate?

---

In calculating the probabilities for attribute profession,As the prior probabilities are 0.5 and taking m=1

```
P(teacher|selected)=(2+0.5)/(3+1)=5/8  
P(farmer|selected)=(1+0.5)/(3+1)=3/8  
P(Business|Selected)=(0+0.5)/(3+1)= 1/8
```

But shouldn't the class probabilities add up to 1? In this case it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"m estimate of probability" is confusing.

In the given examples, m and p should be like this.

```
m = 3 (* this could be any value. you can specify this.)
p = 1/3 = |v| (* number of unique values in the feature)
```

If you use `m=|v| then m*p=1,` so it is called Laplace smoothing. **"m estimate of probability"** is the generalized version of Laplace smoothing.

In the above example you may think m=3 is too much, then you can reduce m to 0.2 like this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use *m*=1. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Multinomial_naive_Bayes) if you choose *m*=1 it is called Laplace smoothing. *m* is generally chosen to be small (I read that *m*=2 is also used). Especially if you don't have that many samples in total, because a higher *m* distorts your data more.

**Background information:** The parameter *m* is also known as pseudocount (virtual examples) and is used for [additive smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing). It prevents the probabilities from being 0. A zero probability is very problematic, since it puts any multiplication to 0. I found a nice example illustrating the problem in this book preview [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/thoughtful-machine-learning/9781449374075/ch04.html) (search for pseudocount)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the uniform prior should be 1/3, not 1/2. This is because you have 3 professions, so you're assigning equal prior probability to each one. Like this, mp=1, and the probabilities you listed sum to 1.

Answer (score -1):

### From p = uniform priors and with m equal to the size of the vocabulary.

Will get :

[image: Result]